# Retrieving values from mongodb array using java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am using mongo driver 3.4 v and trying to get the different status and startDate data from the below record:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5911c47ae4b0bf49e7b22bcb"),
        "statusLog" : [
            {
                "status" : "Submitted",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2017-05-09T13:30:34.036Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2017-05-09T13:37:54.777Z")
            },
            {
                "status" : "Cancelled",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2017-05-09T13:37:54.777Z")
            }
        ],
        "lastChangeDate" : ISODate("2017-05-09T13:37:54.777Z"),
        "status" : "Cancelled",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-05-09T13:30:34.036Z")
    }
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
  MongoCursor<Document> curs = col.find().iterator();
    BasicDBList sList = new BasicDBList();

    while (curs.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = curs.next();
        sList.add(doc.get("statusLog"));
        Object id = doc.get("_id"); 
    }
```

Could you provide any help or pointers how to get the status and startDate under statusLog. I tried different ways to get these two items but couldn't get it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to cast the `doc.get("statusLog")` to `List` first and iterate to collect the fields under each status log. Something like 
       `List<Document> statusLogs =  doc.get("statusLog", List.class);
            for (Document statusLog : statusLogs) {
                sList .add(statusLog.getString("status"));
                sList .add(statusLog.getDate("startDate"));
    }`

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Veeram. Your solution works well!!